# How to get subtypes using `DartType` class from the `analyzer`?

Tags: dart, analyzer, dart-analyzer

How can I get the subtypes of an element using the class [DartType](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.29.3/analyzer.dart.element.type/DartType-class.html) from the analyzer package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those wondering, the [`DartType`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.29.3/analyzer.dart.element.type/DartType-class.html) class is a statically *resolved* type that is created by the `analyzer` package, Dart's static tooling package. The author is asking how they can get other types given a `DartType` - I think you mean *super* types, i.e. types that you inherit or implement.

(If you simply wanted to check if the `DartType` *is a subtype* of something, you could use [`isSubtypeOf`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.29.3/analyzer.dart.element.type/DartType/isSubtypeOf.html))

We can get a hold of the `Element` that the `DartType` originates from, and then, if it is a `ClassElement`, simply return all of the super types, otherwise perhaps default to an empty list:

```
import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart';

/// Returns all sub-types of [type].
Iterable<DartType> getSubTypes(DartType type) {
  final element = type.element;
  if (element is ClassElement) {
    return element.allSupertypes;
  }
  return const [];
}
```

This is in `analyzer` version `0.29.3`.

Comment: sorry, I want the subtypes of a generic type, ie: `List<String>` I want `String`.

Comment: should I change the question?

Comment: That or ask another one - I imagine this will be useful for someone :)

Comment: other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754912/how-to-get-the-subtypes-of-a-generic-type-using-darttype-from-analyzer-packa

Comment: @matanlurey do you know how to get DartType from a Type ? Because on my generator I want to use isSubtypeOf but can't as I only have the Type not the dartType to compare to