# How to get the subtypes of a generic type using `DartType` from `analyzer` package?

Tags: dart, analyzer, dart-analyzer

How can I get the subtypes of an element using the class [DartType](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.29.3/analyzer.dart.element.type/DartType-class.html) from the `analyzer` package?

for example if the type is `List<String>`, I would like to get `String`. Also will be useful to get if the type is `generic`.

Another more complex example would be `Map<String, String>` where I want to get a list of the subtypes, in this case: `[String, String]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This one is a little tricky - because [`DartType`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.29.3/analyzer.dart.element.type/DartType-class.html) actually itself has some super types - the one that will interest you here is [`ParameterizedType`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/analyzer/0.29.3/analyzer.dart.element.type/ParameterizedType-class.html):

```
import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart';

Iterable<DartType> getGenericTypes(DartType type) {
  return type is ParameterizedType ? type.typeArguments : const [];
}
```

I don't know if it's possible to *know* if the type is generic - after all, it's just a type. But you can check if the type *accepts* generic parameters, again, using `ClassElement`:

```
import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart';

bool canHaveGenerics(DartType type) {
  final element = type.element;
  if (element is ClassElement) {
    return element.typeParameters.isNotEmpty;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Hope that helps!